# Cant mount children component to ref

Tags: vue.js

I have a problem with [VuePaginator](https://github.com/hootlex/vuejs-paginator) , that I can mount it to my Vue app $refs properties. I am doing everyting according to docs, here is my component in the html:

```
<v-paginator :resource.sync="comments" ref="vpaginator" resource_url="{{route('api.item.comments', $item->pk_i_id)}}"></v-paginator>
```

The pagination works correctly, but I can't trigger ***fetchData()*** from the vuejs code, because paginator is not getting mounted to ***vm.$refs.vpaginator***.

Here is the code that I use:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#comments',
    data : {
        comments: [],
        newComment: {
            text: ""
        }
    },
    components: {
        VPaginator: VuePaginator
    },
    methods: {
        addComment: function(comment){
            var vm = this;
            this.$http.post($('meta[name="item-url"]').attr('content'), comment)
                .then(function(response){
                    toastr.success(response.data.result);
                    comment.text = "";

                    vm.$.vpaginator.fetchData();
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    if(error.data){
                        toastr.error(error.data.text[0]);
                    }
                })
        },
        logRefs: function(){
            console.log(this.$refs.vpaginator);
        }
    }
});
```

I have created ***logRefs()*** function to check the $ref property and it is always undefined.

Comment: What version of VueJS you are using ?

Comment: @BelminBedak 1.0.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the Version 1 of VueJS, usage is a bit different - check this demo http://jsbin.com/rupogesumo/edit?html,js,output

```
<v-paginator :resource.sync="comments" v-ref:vpaginator resource_url="{{route('api.item.comments', $item->pk_i_id)}}"></v-paginator>
```

Docs Reference: https://v1.vuejs.org/api/#v-ref